# how to fit a div inside curved div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div inside a div,

```
<div style="background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px; border-radius: 10px;" id="div1"> 
        <div style="background-color: orange;" id="div2">
            testing
        </div>
</div>
```

The **div2** which sits at the top of the **div1**, does not align with the curve of **div1**.

Even if I change the border radius of **div2**, I cannot align with **div1**'s radius curve perfectly. How to remove the **div2** which is excess outside the curve of **div1**?

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sjj3k6br/)

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sjj3k6br/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:add overflow:hidden

```html
<div style="background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px; border-radius: 10px; overflow:hidden" id="div1"> 
        <div style="background-color: orange;padding-left:5px" id="div2">
            testing
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the parent to hide the overflow of its child:

`overflow: hidden;` on div1